# Amazon SNS Ignores FilterPolicy on email protocol (PHP SDK)

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

The following code subscribes to an SNS HTTP Endpoint:

```
$protocol = 'http';
$endpoint = 'http://test.com/endpoint.php';
$filterPolicyTest = array(
    'test' => ['1','2','3']
);
$filterPolicyString = json_encode($filterPolicyTest);

$result = $this->awsClient->subscribe([
        'Protocol' => $protocol,
        'Endpoint' => $endpoint,
        'ReturnSubscriptionArn' => true,
        'TopicArn' => 'myTopicARN',
        'Attributes' => [
            'FilterPolicy' => $filterPolicyString,
        ],
    ]);
```

After confirming the subscription, I can view the subscription in the AWS console and see the Filter policy.

Now I try the same thing but with an email:

```
$protocol = 'email';
$endpoint = 'myemail@gmail.com';
$filterPolicyTest = array(
    'test' => ['1','2','3']
);
$filterPolicyString = json_encode($filterPolicyTest);

$result = $this->awsClient->subscribe([
        'Protocol' => $protocol,
        'Endpoint' => $endpoint,
        'ReturnSubscriptionArn' => true,
        'TopicArn' => 'myTopicARN',
        'Attributes' => [
            'FilterPolicy' => $filterPolicyString,
        ],
    ]);
```

No errors are thrown. I successfully receive a confirmation email and click the link to subscribe. But, in the AWS console for this subscription, I see:

[image]

The FilterPolicy attribute is completely ignored.

I am using the PHP SDK version 3. [Here is the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-sns-2010-03-31.html#subscribe) for this request. I tried submitting a FilterPolicy both as an array and json encoded string with no luck.

Comment: Have you tried `['FilterPolicy' => json_encode($filterPolicyString)]`?

Comment: No. Wouldn't that be double encoding the FilterPolicy? Additionally, the HTTP Endpoint already works so I doubt its a format issue.

Comment: `$filterPolicyString` is a string not an array, so json_encode wouldn't work anyways.

Comment: Ahh never mind I didn't see this line `$filterPolicyString = json_encode($filterPolicyTest);` my bad

Comment: Not sure why it doesn't work but you could try to use [setSubscriptionAttributes()](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-sns-2010-03-31.html#setsubscriptionattributes)